Elliptic curve short Weierstrass equation that always returns a quadratic residue modulo curve field?
Currently I'm encoding my message using short Weierstrass equation $y^2 = x^3 + Ax + B$ and elliptic curve is NIST-P256, which has $A$, $B$ and $P$(elliptic curve field size) known. Encoding itself is done in a for loop and lasts until Jacobi symbol is equals to 1 ($y^2 / P$) or until $2^8$ iterations are made. Each iteration I make +1 to the $x$ value.
My question is - is there any other variations of a short Weierstrass equation that allows direct encoding (without iteration), so that $y^2$ is guaranteed to be a quadratic residue modulo $P$ straight away?

If the encoding method doesn't need to be invertible, there is Hash2Curve (RFC 9380) methods.  Of course, if you are, say, doing ECElGammal, that doesn't work (but in that case, why aren't you using ECIES?)

@poncho thanks for a quick feedback! Encoding should be invertible, indeed, so I wish to retrieve plaintext in some time back.. And yes, I use EC ElGamal. I use ElGamal and not ECIES to support regular/distributed/homomorphic encryption schemes

No.
If such a curve existed, then for all $p$ possible values of $x$ we would be able to find 2 corresponding $y$ values that satisfy the equation. This would mean that the curve would have $2p+1$ points which is not allowed by Hasse's theorem.
ETA: Your comment is not fully clear to me, but here are two examples where we can map elements mod $p$ to elliptic curve points without iteration. Note that the curves in these examples are super-singular curves which are vulnerable to the MOV attack.
In the first example, we take the curve $y^2=x^3+Ax$ modulo a prime $p$ that is 3 mod 4. Given any $x$ we can compute $x^3+Ax$ and test the Legendre/Jacobi symbol; if it is +1 we find a corresponding $y$; if the Jacobi symbol is -1 we note that $(-x)^3+A(-x)=-(x^3+Ax)$ has Jacobi symbol +1 and so we can find a $y$ corresponding to $-x$.
In the second example, we take the curve $y^2=x^3+B$ modulo a prime $p$ that is 2 mod 3. We can encode our message as our choice of $y$ coordinate. The expression $y^2-B$ then has precisely one cube root which we can take to be the corresponding $x$ coordinate.

thanks! But I don't want that all $y^2$ would result in a quadratic residue modulo curve field. I do know that exactly half of all elements in a curve field are quadratic residues, I'm seeking for a way to find it straight away, without iteration. Just like we do with discrete logarithms of Zp ElGamal, where we check first, if the $value/Field_order$ has a Jacobi of 1, and if not, then we do $new_value = Field_order/value$. So I'm just looking for the same logic in elliptic curves

I saw your addition to the comment. That sounds very logical, however, the provided solution doesn't work for NIST-P384, however works for NIST-P256. The solution I meant is to negate the result of a Weierstrass func
